# Why is expressJS route blocking all others when receiving big file upload?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

for a long time I used to believe that while nodeJS/expressJS is single-threaded, at least everything involving I/O runs in parallel. not much so: I discovered that a single route which is receiving a big request (large file upload) actually is blocking all other requests, even before the route code (my code) is actually being processed. Maybe I am not writing it correctly?  this is my expressJS route code:

```
import express from 'express'
import {asyncHandler} from '../../helpers/asyncHandler'
import multer from 'multer'

const adminRoute = express.Router()
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

adminRoute.post('/UploadAddressesXlsx', upload.any(), asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log('started handling file upload')
  res.status(200).type('json').send('finished')
}))


export default adminRoute
```

so when a user starts uploading a file to that route, the "*started handling file upload*" message is ***not*** yet shown. only after the entire upload is complete, it is indeed shown. and during the upload, all other routes for this expressJS server are non-responsive. This means that it is the I/O that is blocking the server, it is not even my code. Is there a better way to handle this?

Edit: even when I send the upload to a different route (without Multer, and such that not expecting any upload...) still the blocking behavior is observed.

Answer (score -1):

That is how the multer middleware that you are using works.  It is not blocking OTHER requests.  It is processing THIS request.  You can freely run other requests on your server.

The multer middleware handles the entire upload before calling the rest of your route handler.  That's because the rest of your route handler is expecting `req.files` to be fully populated with all the uploads ready for processing and that can't happen until multer is done with the entire upload.

The *"started handling file upload"* message won't show (by design) until multer has processed the entire upload.  But, other requests can be freely processed by your Express server during this time.

FYI, there are other ways to use multler, involving streams where you can participlate in the live processing of the uploads.  But, the way you are using multer here, you're asking it to do everything for you and only call your request handler when it's done with the upload.

> during the upload, all other routes for this expressJS server are non-responsive

This will not be the case.  Depending upon how you are testing this, you may be seeing a restriction implemented by the browser (not by the server).  If you try other requests from different browsers, they should work just fine.  For testing purposes, just try loading a simple web page from your server into a different browser while an upload is happening.  That should work just fine during the upload.

Comment: unfortunately, the blocking is real. I opened Safari (in parallel to the Chrome which did the upload) and the requests in the Safari had to wait until Chrome's upload was complete.

Comment: It's possible that Safari and Chrome (if on IOS) are using the same browser engine (I don't think Chrome is allowed by Apple to use their own browser engine on IOS) so this could still be one browser engine.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem, might help others encountering similar issue:
the issue is with the VPN (in this case Fortinet Fortigate) which apparently applies a single-request network policy. I will approach the network administrator to reconfigure the product.